# largest number without conditional operator

Tags: c

can any one please elaborate how to find largest of four numbers without using conditional operator.for 3 numbers i have done but for four numbers how to write different comparisons.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Also, you should accept more answers.

Comment: Show your example. Does *without using conditional operations* means that you can use hidden ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard way to compute `min` or `max` in 2's complement arithmetics without using conditionals:

```
int max(int a, int b){
    unsigned diff = b - a;  // negative if a > b
    int sign = -(diff >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)); // -1 if a > b, 0 otherwise
    return (a & sign) | (b & ~sign);
}
```

it can be easily scaled.

Answer (score 1):

```
void main()
{
  int a, b;
  printf("Enter a and b:");
  scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
  printf("Maximum number is %d", max(a, b));
  getch();
}
int max(int a, int b)
{
  int c, temp;
  c = a - b;
  temp = c + abs(c);
  // To check if the difference is negative or not
  if(temp) //As suggested by R..
    return b;
  else
    return a;
}
```

This code is for compare two numbers. Make this comparison for all numbers.

Comment: `==` is a conditional operator

Comment: Then switch the if/else and use `if (temp)`.

Comment: `abs()` has a hidden conditional.

Comment: Don't use '`void main()`; if nothing else, it is non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

you can find max of two number a,b by using following trick:

> (abs(a+b)+abs(a-b))/2

Extend the trick for as many numbers you want.